# Why am I getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsExceptiuon when I copy and paste input?

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I made sure the buffer is completely empty(ie no newline). It only works if I type the input manually.

If I copy and paste the input, I have to press an extra "Enter" which is probably the culprit to causing the exception:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0`

My question is essentially: Why does this happen only when I copy and paste the input and how do I rectify it?

```
public class Skener {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //Creating scanner and associated input variables
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    int r,zr,c,zc;
    
    
    //Reading input variables
    r=scan.nextInt();
    c=scan.nextInt();
    zr=scan.nextInt();
    zc=scan.nextInt();
    
    scan.nextLine();//cleaning up buffer
    
    
    char[][] matrix= {};
    
    matrix=read2DArray(r, c, matrix); <--Error happens in this method
    .....
}

public static char[][] read2DArray(int r,int c,char[][] twoD_array)
{
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int row,col;
    String input;
    twoD_array=new char[r][c];
    
    for(row=0;row<=r-1;row++)
    {   
        input=scan.nextLine();
        for(col=0;col<=c-1;col++)
        {
        
            twoD_array[row][col]=input.charAt(col); <-- Error occurs at this line
        }
    
    }
    
    return twoD_array;
}
```

---

Here is a sample input:

```
3 3 1 2
.x.
x.x
.x.
```

and corresponding sample output:

```
..xx..
xx..xx
..xx..
```

Edit:

Crashes on inputs like the above-given sample input.
Value of `col` upon crash is 0.

Comment: What is the value of `input` when the exception occurs? What is the value of `col` when the exception occurs?

Comment: The exception occurs for any appropriate input. The sample input also gives me the exception when I copy and paste it

Comment: You have to debug and check.

Comment: When copying, it is not copying `\n` char. Debug and check the value of `input` when exception occurs.

Comment: I think the value of `col` is 0.Here is 1 possible input:                                                                                                   
`3 3 1 2
.x.
x.x
.x.` (refer to above sample input,it doesnt display properly in comment)

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam  @Azodious I tried debugging with print statments(yet to learn using debugger), it seems to skip a line after entering the loop containing `col` as counter the 2nd time and crashes

Comment: `I think the value` There is no need to guess. Use the debugger.

Comment: @mjwills I don't know how to use the debugger. I used print statements and it crashes the 2nd time `col` is 0.

Comment: Why don't you check `input.length()` in the loop like this: `for(col=0, n = input.length(); col < n; col++)`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Now I have to press "Enter" twice but it doesn't crash. But the output is wong(it comes out kind of malformed)

Answer (score -1):

because of the extra characters you copy and you didn't notice

**see:**

[when you copy the image notice the extra characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w33IA.png)